# What does "don't tell it to nobody" mean?

Tags: expressions

What does "**don't tell it to nobody**" mean?

does it mean "**tell it to everyone**"?

[And Grammar says](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/nothing)

> GRAMMAR: Negatives Don’t use nothing with another negative word such
>   as ‘not’. Use anything. You say: I could not find anything suitable.
>   ✗Don’t say: I could not find nothing suitable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you were to parse the sentence literally, that's what it would mean. (Or perhaps *tell it to anyone* or *tell it to someone*.)

However, in reality, it's a kind of double-negative slang.

What it really means, idiomatically, is:

> Don't tell (it to) anyone.

---

It's the same kind of informal expression as:

> I didn't do nothing.

This expression, despite its literal meaning, is actually used to express:

> I didn't do anything.

---

In this context, *nobody* and *nothing* don't have their normal meaning; instead, they are used as a way to increase the emphasis on the negative.

Comment: I want to upvote but that rep is just so cool.

Comment: @user178049 LOL I didn't even notice. (I'm sure it won't stay at 22,222 much longer.)

Comment: but GRAMMAR says: Negatives
Don’t use nothing with another negative word such as ‘not’. Use anything. You say:
I could not find anything suitable.
✗Don’t say: I could not find nothing suitable.
https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/nothing

Comment: @Tom This use of double negative is non-standard (ie. ungrammatical in the standard English). So that capitalized 'grammar' plays no role in this case. The sentence is already ungrammatical, but it's a kind of construction that you will always hear in non-standard varieties. That's why, as already pointed out, it should be considered slang.

Comment: This is usually a colloquial construction - commonly seen in gangster movies